# python.exe crashes when importing `theano`

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I am using Anaconda(2.2 64bit) on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.
When I try to

```
import theano
```

Python crashes without infomation. I installed `theano` using Anaconda.

Does anyone know where this problem comes from?

Comment: What are your `THEANO_FLAGS`? Are you trying to use a GPU?

Comment: I don not use gpu,so did not set it

Comment: Try forcing it to use the CPU (put `device=cpu` in `THEANO_FLAGS`). The flags can be set by following the instructions in the documentation: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a missing, or incorrectly configured C compiler. There's a lot of help about installing Theano on Windows [in the documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html).

In particular, make sure you've run

```
conda install mingw libpython
```

Comment: I had installed mingw and libpython

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by using anaconda 2.10 instead of anaconda 2.20.but I still have no idear about the reason.If anyone can tell me,I will appreiciate