# Installing Theano on windows machine

Tags: python, theano

I have read through

[How to install Theano on Anaconda Python 2.7 x64 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687103/how-to-install-theano-on-anaconda-python-2-7-x64-on-windows/36523637#36523637)

I installed Anaconda 2 and followed the steps and I can import theano, however once in a while I get a windows crash message window on python crash similar to this:

[python.exe crashes when importing `theano`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050976/python-exe-crashes-when-importing-theano)

I have done "conda install mingw libpython" step.

Also when I run theano.test() I get this warning:

pycuda import failed in theano.misc.pycuda_init.

Overall I think there were some more steps in the windows installation page regarding visual studio, and other modules. I have visual studio 2012 installed by microsoft.

Comment: I just uninstalled anaconda and did the steps exactly as specified in the link above. Still I get a warning on theano.test() as: pycuda import failed in theano.misc.pycuda_init.

Comment: have you set your theano flag?

Comment: How do you set up the flag and what is it used for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install theano in Anaconda ver. 2.1 Windows 64 bit for Python 3.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629347/how-do-i-install-theano-in-anaconda-ver-2-1-windows-64-bit-for-python-3-4)

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the theano install instructions fully?

On windows 7 x64, I would advise to either use Canopy from Enthought, which, if you are a student , you can get the complete package for free.

Or, i also used WinPython before, it worked fine.
Although you have to follow all steps, including :

**Installing Windows Software Development Kit version 7.1 or you can install the newest Visual Studio which comes with it and it comes with an option to install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7**

**Installing TDM GCC**

***But be sure to check***

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html

*You might wanna check if you missed any steps.*

I had problems with Anaconda and Theano before. So i gave up on using it.
However a friend had success with it and Theano as well.

Just be sure you have your environment and python setup installed properly prior to theano install.

Doing

```
where gcc
where gendef
where cl
where nvcc
```

***on the Command Prompt Might reveal something...***

Be sure to have installed Windows SDK and last visual studio.